# Extracting 3 best matches using sklearn module

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I'm working on [sample code](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/examples/face_recognition_svm.py) which uses face_recognition python library:

everything's fine except i want to fetch 3 best candidate instead of only the best one which is the result of

```
clf.predict([test_image_enc])
```

I expect output of `[4411, 4455, 5566]` instead of `4411`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `decision_function` method to get the likelihood measure for each class.
This computes the distance from the separating hyperplanes (higher this value, more likely the datapoint belonging to the corresponding class). Then you can pick the `top_n` number of classes as you wish.

```
top_n = 3
sort_inds =  clf.decision_function([test_image_enc]).argsort()
clf.classes_[sort_inds[0][-top_n:][::-1]]
```